# notepad++ regex save custom info, but change brackets type

Tags: regex, notepad++

So.
I have plenty of this straigt in code like

```
*tons of text* get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/randomtextIhavetosave.png') *tons of text*
```

I figured out how to find this kind of text: `get_sprite_ori\('.*?'\)`
But I have to make this text to look kinda like that:

```
 *tons of text* "images/sprites/normal/mi/randomtextIhavetosave.png" *tons of text*
```

I tried "$1" and "images/sprites/$1", but still it changes on "" or "images/sprites/"

If you still didn't understand:
I have tons of blocks like these:

> image mi serious voca =
>   ConditionSwitch("persistent.sprite_time=='sunset'",
>   im.MatrixColor(im.Composite((1050, 1080), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/mi_3_body.png'), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_7dl('normal/mi/mi_3_voca_dress.png'), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/mi_3_serious.png')), im.matrix.tint(0.94,
>   0.82, 1.0)), "persistent.sprite_time=='night'", im.MatrixColor(im.Composite((1050, 1080),  (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/mi_3_body.png'), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_7dl('normal/mi/mi_3_voca_dress.png'), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/mi_3_serious.png')), im.matrix.tint(0.63,
>   0.78, 0.82)), True, im.Composite((1050, 1080),  (0, 0), get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/mi_3_body.png'), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_7dl('normal/mi/mi_3_voca_dress.png'), (0, 0),
>   get_sprite_ori('normal/mi/mi_3_serious.png')))

and I have to get rid of scripts, coz they're in-built in new version of RenPy I use.

Comment: Maybe `get_sprite_ori\('(.*?)'\)` will allow you to use `$1`.

Comment: Yep. Thanks. This worked.
Saved my life from 10 hours of timewasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned Kenney (thanks him in comments), best way was to just adjust my way of handling situation:

So, easiest way is just using instead of

> get_sprite_ori('.*?')

is

> get_sprite_ori('(.*?)')

after that $1 will work.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned, you need to use a capturing group (a pair of unescaped parentheses) to *capture* a part of text with a part of regex pattern. The first such pair will capture the first submatch that can be referenced using `$1` (or `\1`).

As for the regex, you can replace `.*?` with `[^']*` as it is unlikely you can have another `'` before the `)`. And add a word boundary `\b` to match `get` as a whole word:

```
\bget_sprite_ori\('([^']*)'\)
```

And replace with `images/sprites/$1`.

See settings:

[image]